# How to append some character when beforeItemAdd function getting called in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

```
$('#twitter-handles').on('beforeItemAdd', function(event) {
      console.log(event.item);
      var tag = event.item;
      if (!tag.match("^#")) {
        tag = '#'+tag;
      }
      event.item = tag;
      //i want to add tag content to the tags box
      console.log(event.item);
  });
```

if I enter India in tags text box it should be added like `#india`.
I'm using `bootsrap-tagsinput.js`

Comment: what is the problem with this code..?

Comment: its not adding to the UI

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#twitter-handles').on('beforeItemAdd', function(event) {
     var item = event.item;
     if (!item.match("^#")) {
       event.cancel=true;
       event.preventDefault=true;
       item='#'+item;
       $('#twitter-handles').tagsinput('add', item);
     }
});
```

its working fine.

Comment: Was looking for this for like an hour. Thanks for the answer.